# how to maintain scrollbar at the bottom, instead of going to the middle when chat refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrollbar

I am making a chat where, on load, the scrollbar scrolls to the bottom. This is the JS function that gets called on load:

```
 <script>
function updateScroll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
    var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
    element.scrollTop = elementHeight
}
window.onload = updateScroll;
 </script>
```

Then, with this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {       
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');}, 1000);
    });
```

..the chat gets updated every second. What happens though, is that when it updates, the scrollbar goes to the middle, instead of remaining at the bottom. How can I make my chat stay at the bottom, when the last code makes the chat refresh?

You can see a working example here: http://www.friendsinclass.co.nf/
Please let me know, thank you!

Comment: You could call the your function updateScroll() along with updating the chatlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple thoughts, first you'll probably want to use recursion to call the AJAX request on AJAX success.  Using `setInterval()` could result in any number of AJAX requests happening at any given time, depending on how long they take to return.

Second, to prevent the scroll bar from jumping to the bottom if the user has scrolled, you'll probably want to give them a notice and the ability to jump to the bottom if there is new content.

Considering those points, something like this would work:

**JavaScript**

```
var infiniteUpdate = true;
var intervalTimer;
var id = 0;
var log = document.getElementById("chatlogs");


function updateScroll() {
    log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight;
    $('#messagearea').hide()
}

function updateLog() {

    //if an interval timer was set, we clear it
    if(typeof intervalTimer == 'number') { 
        clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    } 
    id++;



    $.ajax({
      url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?id=" + id,
    })
    .done(function( data ) {

        //bottomOfScroll is the height .scrollTop must be at for the user to be at the bottom of the scrollbar
        var bottomOfScroll = log.scrollHeight - log.clientHeight;
        //isScrollable detects if the element can scroll
        var isScrollable = log.scrollHeight != log.clientHeight;

        //if the user is not at the bottom and the element has a scrollbar
        if(log.scrollTop != bottomOfScroll && isScrollable) {
            //when true, it means the user has scrolled
            hasUserScrolled = true;
        } else {
            //when false, we are still at the bottom of the element
            hasUserScrolled = false;
        }

        //append the new data
        $('#chatlogs').append('<p>'+data[0].title+'</p>')

        //if we had detected a scroll
        if(hasUserScrolled) {
            //show the message and allow the user to click to jump to the bottom
            $('#messagearea').show();
        } else {
            //if the user hasnt scrolled, move the scroll position to the bottom and hide the message
          updateScroll();
        }

        //if we wanted to do something to break recursion, we could do that here
        if(infiniteUpdate) { 
            //set a new timer for 2.5 seconds
            intervalTimer = setInterval( updateLog, 2500);
        }

    });

}


$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#messagearea').on('click', updateScroll)

    updateScroll();
    updateLog();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="chatlogs">

</div>
<div id="messagearea">Scroll Down to View New Messages
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chatlogs {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#messagearea { display: none; }
```

JS Fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/9tbrgrkn/3/ with a test AJAX endpoint

Hope that helps!

Comment: that helps but not in the way I want it to. Doing what you do, it will update the scroll every 2 seconds. Which is quite bothering if someone's reading old messages. I want the scroll only to upload (go down) on load of the page, and STAY DOWN when the chat refreshes, UNLESS someone is actually going up and scrolling up

Comment: Good point @Gram.  I updated the answer with a more robust solution.

Comment: thanks for that, but the fiddle doesn't seem to work! I updated it with some text in the scroll area https://jsfiddle.net/9tbrgrkn/4/

Comment: It doesn't scroll with content already present because the scroll position is not at the bottom.  If you want it to start at the bottom just add `updateScroll();` to the document ready statement:  http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/9tbrgrkn/5/

Comment: I tried putting this exactly as written in the fiddle in a webpage, but it won't update with the verses. What am I missing?

Comment: No idea.  You'd have to recreate the problem in a JS fiddle or post a link to  where the problem can be reproduced.  Its difficult to troubleshoot your code without seeing your code.

Comment: could you please look at my new post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309153/how-to-make-scrollbar-in-chat-scrolldown-when-new-messages-arrive-not-sent-by-y and help me out with inserting the code you posted in this question? Thanks