# How to make scrollbar in chat scrolldown when new messages arrive (not sent by you)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrollbar

Actual page reference: www.friendsinclass.co.nf

I'm building a simple chat, and I have one problem. The chat scrollbar auto-scrolls down when loading the page, as you can see in the updatescroll() function at the bottom. Currently, updatescroll is also called every second in setInterval within $(document).ready, in order to scroll down when a new message is written. As you can see, there is also a call to autoscroll() in submitChat(), which means autoscroll gets called everytime I SUBMIT a message.  The problem is that if a user that OTHER THAN ME submits a message, autoscroll will not get called, hence me setting autoscroll every 1 second to solve this.

PROBLEM: if a user wants to scroll up to see old messages, autoscroll will bring the scroll down again every 1 second, making his search useless. HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM IN AS EASY WAY? I've tried many ways but it won't work, also I am not very good with Jquery so PLEASE be as simple as possible.

Many thank you! JS below

```
function submitChat() {
    form1.uname.readOnly = true;
    form1.uname.style.border = 'none';
    var uname = form1.uname.value;
    var msg = form1.msg.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 100);
            }

    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?uname='+uname+'&msg='+msg,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 100);
}



    $(document).ready(
            function(e) {
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
 setInterval(function({$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');updateScroll();}, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){ updateScroll(); }, 1200);

    });

</script>

   <script language="javascript">
    function toggleState(item){
       if(item.className == "on") {
          item.className="off";
       } 
       else {
          item.className="on";
       }
    }
 </script>

<script>

function updateScroll() {               

    var element = document.getElementById("chatlogs");
    var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
    element.scrollTop = elementHeight;
}
window.onload = updateScroll;
</script>
```

PS One solution could be using a toggleswitch I created, a simple button which turns red and blue. For instance, when clicked it could call updateScroll() every second, and turn it off again when clicked again. But I don't know how to connect its changing class to the functions.

CSS of toggle switch:

```
.on  { background:blue; }
  .off { background:red; }
```

HTML Toggle:

```
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="button" 
    class="off" onclick="toggleState(this)" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is different than the one you'd asked earlier:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271704/how-to-maintain-scrollbar-at-the-bottom-instead-of-going-to-the-middle-when-cha/  The solution is going to be similar, detect if the user has scrolled the chat in the AJAX response, if it hasn't, scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but could you please implement your code from the previous question in my code here? Because I have tried doing so but something's wrong.